# $f_n'(x) \to g(x)$ uniformly on compacts, then $f_n(x)\to \int_0^x g(t) dt$ uniformly on compacts.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence

Consider the series of function $\{ f_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and suppose each $f_n$ is $C^1$ and $f_n(0)=0.$

Prove that if $f_n'(x)$ uniformly converges to $g(x)$ on arbitrary compact sets, then $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $\displaystyle\int_0^x g(t) dt$ on arbitrary compact sets.

I have to ideas (i)(ii) to solve this problem, but I 'm not sure whether (ii) is correct or not.

---

**Solution (i)**

Let $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$ be an arbitrary compact set and let $\epsilon >0$.

I can choose $c>0$ s.t. $-c<a, b <c.$

Since $f' _n \to g$ uniformly on arbitrary compact sets, there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ s.t.
$$n \geqq N \Rightarrow |f_n'(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon \mathrm{\ for \ } \forall x\in [a,b].$$
When $n \geqq N,$
\begin{align}
\left| f_n (x)-\int_0^x g(t) dt \right|
&=\left| \int_0^x \big(f_n'(t)-g(t)\big)dt\right|\\
&\leqq \left| \int_0^x |f_n'(t)-g(t)| dt\right|\\
&\leqq \left| \int_0^x \epsilon dt\right| \\
&=|x| \epsilon \\
&<c\epsilon \mathrm{\ for\ } \forall x \in [a,b].
\end{align}
Thus $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $\displaystyle\int_0^x g(t) dt$ on $[a,b]$.

**Solution(ii)**

Let $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$.

I have $f_n(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^x f_n'(t) dt+ f_n (0)=\int_0^x f_n'(t) dt$ on $[a,b]$.

Letting $n\to \infty,$
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^x f_n'(t) dt=\int_0^x \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n'(t) dt=\int_0^x g(t) dt$ on $[a,b]$.

Thus $f_n(x) \to \displaystyle\int_0^x g(t) dt$ on $[a,b]$.

---

In (ii), I think that I only proved $$\forall x\in [a,b]\ ; \ f_n(x) \to \int_0^x g(t) dt.$$ This seems not to be  uniform convergence but to be pointwise convergence.

Isn't (ii) good ? And does (i) make sense ?

Comment: In (i) you should control $|f_n’(x) -g(x)|$ on $[-c,c]$ to use this control in the integral. Except for this everything seems all right and as you pointed out your second idea does not bring uniform convergence.